# Compile newer software for outdated versions of the same distribution

Tags: fedora, compiling

I am using Fedora 17 and want to compile and use [Geary](http://www.yorba.org/projects/geary/). However, the required library versions are only available in Fedora 18.

For various reasons I want (need!) to stick to F17 so, I was thinking of compiling in Fedora 18 (in Virtualbox) and then moving across to F17. However, I a presume once I do this and try to run on F17 it will complain about missing libraries.

Is there a way to compile on F18 and it pull in all the required libraries into a folder that I can just copy across?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Cross compiling usually means generating binary files for a different system architecture, not for another distribution on the same architecture. Anyway you may be able to compile software using [_static_ linking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library) instead of dynamic linking, such that the required library calls are included in your new binary (at the expense of a bigger binary file size)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reasons why you want to stick to Fedora 17, but you should consider seriously updating/upgrading your software/hardware [since Fedora 17 will reach End of Life (EOL) in July 30](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=292181), which also will allow you to compile/install your code in Fedora 18 and run it natively.

If you still want to stay in Fedora 17 stubbornly you could try what @Tobias said, or compile and install the necessaries libraries against your Fedora 17 installation which will backport the code and run natively on your system. **But keep in mind that something might not work as expected and this is not recommended.**